Google Sheet - If formula
I need help writing a formula that cell's B7 & C7 will return specific text if cell J7 has specific text. (See below)
if Cell J7 says:    Then Cell B7 shoould return:    and Cell C7 should return:
A                   7:25                            8:22
B                   8:26                            9:23
C                   9:27                            10:24
HS Flex            10:28                            11:07 
MS Flex            10:58                            11:37
D                  11:41                            12:38
E                  12:42                            1:39
F                  1:43                             2:40


You need to edit this, it is very confusing. What is in cell J7?  What should be returned by cell C7?

The simplest way to do this is with a LOOKUP formula and creating a reference range where you write this equivalences. For example with XLOOKUP and the range M:O.

=XLOOKUP(J7,M:M,N:N)

Or you can use ARRAYFORMULA and return both columns together:

=ARRAYFORMULA(XLOOKUP(J7,M:M,N:O))

